# how to expand the subgrid in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a gridview data and this gridview have subgrid too.
in the first column of the grid view having + symbol so that i can expand the grid to see subgrid.. but now problem is I need to have a button in the bottom of the grid to expand all the gridview subgrid at a time..

Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET-MVC doesn't come with any GridView capabilities, and the control for ASP.NET isn't compatible ( http://forums.asp.net/t/1216861.aspx ) - there certainly many other libraries you could use to achieve it - perhaps here http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/06/04/Code-based-ASPNET-MVC-GridView.aspx

Comment: What the deuce?  Who are you and why'd you take the name tncbbthositg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a class to every button that is used to expand row and then use jQuery `trigger`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><button class='expand-row-button'>+</button></td><td>other things</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><button class='expand-row-button'>+</button></td><td>other things</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><button class='expand-row-button'>+</button></td><td>other things</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="$('.expand-row-button').trigger('click');">Expand all rows</button>
```

** EDIT **

Because you are using jqGrid, you should look at [expandSubgridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid) method. This method is used to expand row with specified id. You can iterate through rows in your view and generate code to expand every row.

Comment: Thanks for your replay..I need to place the button under the Grid and I need to expand all the rows at one button click event...
please is the above code do the same thing?
thanks

Comment: what is this Expand-row-button? from where we need to give this?

Comment: If every button used to expand row has class `expand-row-button` and you use jQuery then that should work. This code creates button, which when is clicked, triggers clicking of all expand buttons.

Comment: http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0giikm.htm

same i have the gridview like this.. same way i need to keep the Button in the bottom of the grid to expand all the + sing at a time.. 
thanks

Comment: @tncbbthositg: Maybe this post will help: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/treegrid/expand-all-and-collapse-all-functionality-in-tree-grid/

Comment: Please can you look in to this sameple code
http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0giikm.htm
same I have like this.. I dont have any button in the grid.. directly i have the grid data with first colum + i need to expand all the + to show subgrid data on one button click
thanks

Comment: pleae can you tell me how to iterate throw my row to expand all the rows?thanks

Comment: <button onclick="$('.expand-row-button').trigger('click');">Expand all rows</button>
this code is not working nothing is happening on button click event..
thanks